# React Native counter on long press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a counter in a React Native app, and I've got the basic functionality working. I have an input, two buttons, and the counter changes when I press one of the buttons. Now, I want to implement a feature where if I hold down one of the buttons, the counter increases faster without repeatedly pressing the button.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("1");
const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

<TouchableHighlight onPressIn={handlePressIn} onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
  <View style={styles.buttonFrame}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>+</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>

function handlePressIn() {
 let setIntervalFunction = setInterval(() => {
   setValue((parseInt(value) + 1).toString());
   console.log(value);
 }, 2000);

 setIntervalId(setIntervalFunction);
}
function handlePressOut() {
 intervalId.clearInterval();
}
```

This is what I try so far, create a function that increase the number, with a `setIntervall` function, and store this function to stop is when the button is released.

I have encountered two issues:

1. The value always stays at 1, even though I expect it to increment. It seems like
   setValue isn't working as expected.
2. I can't stop the `setInterval` function when releasing the button, and I'm getting
   an error saying `intervalId.clearInterval is not a function`.

I've seen multiple solutions with a similar idea, but none of them seem to work for me. Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code. It works fine to me.
The error that I found in your code are:

---

(1) The syntax of the clear interval is wrong.
(2) useState is async. So you couldn't log a state next to the setter.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {TouchableHighlight, View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function App(){
  const [value, setValue] = useState("1");
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  function handlePressIn() {
    let setIntervalFunction = setInterval(() => {
      setValue(prev => (Number(prev) + 1).toString());
    }, 2000);

    setIntervalId(setIntervalFunction);
  }

  function handlePressOut() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight style={{padding: 4, paddingHorizontal: 8, backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue', borderRadius: 50}} onPressIn={handlePressIn} onPressOut={handlePressOut}>
        <View>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>+</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it's work perfectly! I'm new in react and also in react native. The ```prev``` variable in ```handlePressIn``` function is came exactly where from?

Comment: The useState hook returns a function to update the state. By default, you can get the previous state value to update the state. This is what the speciality is.